# Expression Intellisense Disabled In Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, intellisense, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using `Report Builder 3.0`.

How can I ***Enable Expression Intellisense*** in ***Report Builder***. I can use `BIDS` but I want to use ***Report Builder*** to create SSRS report.

Is there any `plugin` or some work around to get ***Expression Intellisense*** in ***`Report Builder 3.0`***. Please help.

*Thanks a lot.*